# RxJava: concat several Observables in specific time span

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to write Rx code which would wait for specific time span (once the first Observable comes), concat all Observables with resulting lists during that time span, and process one big list instead of several lists in that time period.

```
.getObservableOnEventHappened() // ArrayList<Data>
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
. // wait for 500ms for all Observables in that time span
. // concat results into one big list of data
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(list -> {
   // do something with data
});
```

I have tried with `buffer` and `window` with time span, but both operators are firing Observers all the time, onNext happens on that time span, every time, which is not what I need.

I would like to avoid multiple allocations with buffer/filter for valid data, buffer/count != 0 etc.

Comment: "wait for 500ms for all Observables in that time span" actually means wait for all the emitted items from that observable in that 500ms time span? So you have one observable firing an array of items?

Comment: I have an observable firing an array of items, correct. Once the first Observable with that arrayList comes, I want to wait next 500ms for others to come and to concatenate all that arrayLists into one.

Comment: This [buffer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#buffer-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) with this [collect](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#collect-java.util.concurrent.Callable-io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer-) should fit your needs. If not you need to give more information.

Comment: Afaik, buffer will be called every timespan. That is not desired behaviour for me. I would like to start timespan once the first item comes, on finish timespan, buffer would do the check again. I don't want check for new Observables until next is fired by getObservableOnEventHappened.